# converts from 2s complement to hex

Tags: c

I have a 16 bit number and this number is in 2s complement example 0xFF25.Let's assume it a=0xFF25 
And I want to get original number 'a' taken From it and save in another hex value such b(b is a 16 bit variable)
Please show me a way to find b.(C code)

example:

```
 signed short int Data_proc(unsigned char data_high, unsigned char data_low)
   {
    signed short int ddata;
    ddata = ((data_high<<8)|data_low);
    return ddata;
   }


   I=Data_proc(a,b);//Now I contain a 2s complement value
```

And I want real hex value I taken from it.

Comment: What, you mean like an assignment? Like `b = a`?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see the negative number in decimal format e.g. see 255 as -1 ?

Comment: Also, all numbers are stored the same in the computer, hexadecimal notation is just that, a *notation* when you input or output the number.

Comment: No..I have  a 2s complement example 0xFF25 And I want the number that 0xFF25 taken from that in hex.Just it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Current **digital** computers only know binary data. Any conversion to another base is just for input/output.

Comment: I got data from an IC  with I2C and this data is in 2s complement format.Therefore I want to got real number.Just it

Comment: `0xFF25` is not 2s complement, but a hexadecimal representation of a binary value which **can** be interpreted as 16 bit 2s complement representation of a negative value (-219).

Comment: What do you mena by "real number"? Float?

Comment: I am so shy because Still my question is not obvious!

Comment: No one.................................. :-o

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right (and I really don't know if I do) you want something like this

```
short a = 0xff25;
printf("hexadecimal %04x equals decimal %hd\n", a, a);
```

---

And like I and others said in comments, the numbers are not *stored* in hexadecimal, decimal or octal, only in binary bits, ones and zeroes. Hexadecimal, decimal and octal are just for *presentation*, to make input or output look nicer, and more readable.

When you do e.g.

```
int a = 0xff25;
```

What is actually stored in `a` is the bits `1111111100100101`. What those bits actually means, it's up to you when you for example print them.

Comment: I got data from an IC with I2C and this data is in 2s complement format.Therefore I want to got real number.Just it

Comment: Carefully read this answer again. It explains exactly what you need. Integer numbers in the C programming language are ALL stored in 2's complement, so the "real" number IS the 2's compliment number.
int i = 4; is using 2's complement and so is int i = -4;

Answer (score 0):

In 2's complement 0xFFFF would be the representation of -1. If you have a variable containing 0xFFFF you would assign it like this:

```
   int16_t a = -1;
   uint16_t b = a;
   printf("%x %d %d %x", a, a, b, b);
```

would print both formats for you as follows.

```
   ffffffff -1 65535 ffff
```

Comment: That is wrong. `-1` in 16 bit 2s complement is `0xFFFF`, not `0x00FF`

Comment: I did not say 0x00FF, everybody knows that you have to sign-extend if you want to show 16 bits, cmon.

Comment: And you can figure out why the first one is printing 32 bits (hint - sign extension and integer promotion rules)

Comment: `0xFF` is **only** for 8 bit 2s complement equal `-1`.  You just should have mentioned that. As OP explicitly asked about 16 bit, you could have simply used `0xFFFF`. That was all I did complain. Note that your format specifiers are wrong. use `inttypes.h` macros for `stdint.h` types. (even if not, they are wrong: on PC, for `short`, it would be `%hx`, etc.) - No need to "figure out", I just know that.

Comment: My original code was (for simplicity) doing EVERYTHING in 8-bit 2's compliment. I have updated to use 16bit :)

Comment: Thanks for listening. I just expected a follow-up question: "why does `0xFF` not equal `-1`?". ;-) Note that the format specifiers are still wrong.